# How to get the requested url name in the lablel text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a lablel on my masterpage and links of the various pages like this

```
<ul id="navigation">
        <li><span class="active">Overview</span></li>
        <li><a href="AdminHome.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="LoginInfo.aspx">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="ProductCategory.aspx">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="ProductSubCategory.aspx">Sub-Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="ProductSubCategory2.aspx">Sub-Category2</a></li>
        <li><a href="CompanyInfo.aspx">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="ProductInfo.aspx">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="ProductStock.aspx">Stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="ProductPhoto.aspx">Photo</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content" class="container_16 clearfix">
        <div class="grid_16">
            <h2>
                <asp:Label ID="lblpagename" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>  </h2>
            <p class="error">
                Something went wronk.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now i want that whenever i click on any link the page name like "Home" , "Register"... get appear in the label text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set it to Page.Title in content page on page_load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = "Some Title";
    }
```

And read that on master page on page_load event

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblpagename.Text = Page.Title;   
    }
```

Comment: sir i did exactly this

Comment: <%@ Page Title="Register YourSelf" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LoginInfo.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_LoginInfo" %>
 it is working

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
 int start=url.LastIndexOf('/');
 int length = url.Length - url.LastIndexOf('/');
 string pageName = url.Substring(start, length).Replace("/","");
 Response.Write(pageName);//or label1.text=pageName;
```

Comment: i dont want the full url  like this

Comment: i just want the page name eg. Inspiete of 'http://localhost:2246/SShoppingWebsite/admin/ProductCategory.aspx ' i  want 'Product Category'

Comment: here is an exception on applying this 'Failed to map the path '/SShopping%20Website/admin/AdminHome.aspx'.'

Answer (score 0):

You have to add text of each page, according to pages name. You can access a control of master page on child like this

```
Label lblMessage = new Label();
lblMessage = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblpagename");
lblMessage.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```